# Retrieving Date format rows in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to make a test on a Date field, so I can get the rows older than 29 days.

My Date field has this format : 2011-01-31 22:18:40

```
SELECT addeddate FROM status
WHERE addeddate // something to test if addeddate >= 29 days
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the data is stored as Date time

Comment: For values stored as DATETIME, you need to decide whether you mean 29 days from the value itself, 29 days from midnight on the same day as the value itself, 29 days from midnight on the day following the value itself, or ummmm, something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT addeddate FROM status
WHERE addeddate <= NOW() - INTERVAL 29 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:
`WHERE addeddate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 29 DAY)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT addeddate FROM status
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), addeddate) >= 29
```